# C# custom Non-Client area resizing issues

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a problem with a "simple" task. Changing the border size of a Form, while preserving all the default behavior.

Changing the border size (Non-Client area) of a window is done by handling [WM_NCCALCSIZE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634(v=vs.85).aspx) in WndProc and, while it does change the border size, it bring some issues with sizing (note that if you set the Non-Client area to 0 you won't experience the same problems do to the fact that you will lose default behavior).

Following the code from Control and Form on ReferenceSource(referencesource.microsoft.com) i've concluded that the problems occurs because of the [AdjustWindowRectEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667(v=vs.85).aspx) function witch calculates the size using a default form border size. Since AdjustWindowRectEx is called multiple times and not all functions using it can be overridden, in certain situations, form gets the wrong size.

Does anyone know of a way to tell AdjustWindowRectEx size of the borders (Non-Client area), or any other way of having custom sized Non-Client area without breaking default behavior?

List of broken behavior:

1. Form will resize each time it is opened in designer (because
   designer serializes ClientSize not Size)
2. Form will resize each time it is restored (from maximized/minimized state)
3. There are some other problems but are not related to the topic

Note: Form will get smaller or bigger depending on FormBorderStyle and the size of the custom client area.

Comment: Don't change the non-client area in the designer. Only apply your changes if your form is outside of a designer, and you're golden :) But as a user, I'd vote for "stop messing with the non-client area" :P

Comment: You identified the problem well, core problem is that AdjustWindowRectEx() always assumes normal window metrics.  Very important in WinForms, it tries very hard to not use the Size property, it is the ClientSize property that really matters.  Above all important because the size of the title bar is unpredictable, very easy to change its font or the button size.  There is no simple fix.  Otherwise the reason why everybody uses a borderless window to fake non-standard chrome.

Comment: The designer part is not so important because A) the end user is never going to see the designer and B) that problem can be avoided by overriding ClientSize and setting Size after setting base.ClientSize. But the problem still remains sense all other functions calling AdjustWindowRectEx don't set ClientSize property but rather sets the client size internali.

Comment: @Hans I am aware of the borderless window option, but at current stage it is impractical to make the change unless there is no other option. Thanks